# How can i compare the values of the attributes on XML and only echo the attribute that contains the string i want with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

So this is an example on how my XML looks like (I use SimpleXML and i would like to keep that way.).

```
<foo>
  <foo1>
    <energy A="false" B="false" C="false" D="true" E="false" F="false"/>
  </foo1>
</foo>
```

This is my PHP so far:

```
$energyR = $xml->foo->foo1->energy[0]->attributes();
foreach($energy as $key => $ener){
 echo $key, $ener;
}
```

The result is the following:

AfalseBfalseCfalseDtrueEfalseFfalse

Now what i want: To iterate through all the attributes and find which one is true and save ONLY the attribute that is true, to a variable.

That means that the result should be:

D (because this is the one which has the value of true)

Any ideas? A complete new code is acceptable too. As i mentioned, i use SimpleXML so please your answers only when it comes to SimpleXML.

Comment: use an `if` statement

Comment: @Ghost And how would this look like? An if statement is easy to say, but how is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   foreach($energy as $key => $ener){
        if ($ener == 'true') {
            echo $key;
        }
    }
```

like this

Comment: Your solution worked. But not with === (identical) but with == (similar). If you want, change it.

Comment: For completeness, `(string)$ener === 'true'` should work as well.